# Multiple Constrained Sum

Tags: syntax, summation, assumptions, constraint

I need to perform a multiple summation, that obeys some conditions. This arises in the study of a statistical physics model. `q=Exp[-β]`.
I would like to ask if someone knows how to speed up the following code, or write an equivalent one in order to perform the multiple summation. The integer variables `a_i`
are to be summed from 0 to infinity while the integers `b_i` run from `-a_i` to infinity and also need to be ordered like:

```
b1>b2>b3>b4 ....>bn
```

and the b summation needs to be performed from the smallest one to the biggest one.

My code to implement this is (ie. 4 objects):

```
Sum[q^(2 a1 + 2 a2 + 2 a3 + 2 a4 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) Boole[b1> b2 > b3 > b4],  
 {b1, -a1 , Infinity}, {b2, -a2 , Infinity}, {b3, -a3 , Infinity}, {b4, -a4 , Infinity}]
```

this gives cases for the a's and then I do the four a summations in a next step ( I also simplify the expressions before the  next step).

```
Sum[%, {a1, 0 , Infinity}, ...]
```

So this works ok up to 3 b's but then it gets infinitely slow for more than 3
and I want to go up to 4 or 5. Is there any way to rewrite this such that it can get faster? ( I have tried to use functions like `UnitStep` but it is again slow )
Important!
  One needs to perform all b sums at once, since otherwise you do not get all the possibilities for a's!

Comment: Any reason you're not just using e.g. `Sum[q^(2 a1 + 2 a2 + 2 a3 + 2 a4 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) , {b1, -a1, 
  Infinity}, {b2, -a2, b1 - 1}, {b3, -a3, b2 - 1}, {b4, -a4, b3 - 1}]` for step 1?

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data** in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @PanagiotisBetzios, what do you mean that the suggestion by ciao is not ordered?  In the summation as he wrote it, `b1> b2 > b3 > b4` is true without invoking the `Boole` operator.

Comment: @rhermans http://www.missmanners.com/ :D

Comment: Che @belisarius ,  is my "greetings" comment too rude? So many links I have to compress the content...

Comment: If you do this it automatically orders also a1, a2 etc , but I need to take cases where say a4>a3 as well as cases where a4<a3, with Boole it seems to take all cases but with this solution it takes only one of the two cases for a's , or at least this is what I think happens...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Greetings, keep up the good work!

Comment: Also the a3=a4 cases etc...

Comment: @rhermans Not rude at all. I always found rather funny the huge amount of info that must be given to new users to get them on track. Looks like these sites are countries with [very particular behaviors](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_in_Rome,_do_as_the_Romans_do) :D , che.

Comment: If you want to check what I am saying try the simple fast b1,b2 case. Sry for what I wrote before, it is not a problem of not ordering, it is a problem of overordering in some sense and not taking all cases into account....

Comment: It is a problem of the lower limits for the b's, if b2<b1 it could be that -a1>-a2 so we are fine. But if -a1<-a2 in the next summation over b1 we are overcounting since by the ordering definition a1's lower limit is set by -a2+1 and not -a1. Boole seems to get this right while the simple solution not.